# I have two arrays. In first array i have some null values and i want to update these null values with second array

Tags: php, arrays

In this I have two arrays, In the first array I have some key have null values in the array. in the second array, I have also the same number of keys in arrays as having null values in first, I want to replace the first array key null values with the second array values

```
$arr1=array(0=>array('quantity'=>1),1=>array(),2=>array('quantity'=>3),3=>array(),4=>array());
```

```
$arr2=array (0 =>array(),1 =>array (),2 =>array(0 =>array('quantity'=>2)));
```

```
$result_array_needed=array(0=>array('quantity'=>1),1=>array(),2=>array('quantity'=>3),3=>array(),4=>array(0 =>array('quantity'=>2)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick answer is good. I think you can simplify it using [array-shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
foreach ($arr1 as &$arr)
    if (empty($arr))  $arr = array_shift($arr2);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/82pD4)

Comment: Yeah, this is almost certainly a better answer. I was being paranoid about what might (or might not) be in `$arr2`.

Comment: Ya thanks dWinder it really simplifies the Nick answer thanks both of you.